# How do I edit areas of text within several HTML elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Observe:

```
<span class="description">

Not This person?
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_self">Click Here</ >

</span>
```

I want to edit the "Not this person" part of the "description" class and also the "click here" part without touching the anchor tag "href" attribute.

Is this possible with jQuery?

Sorry for being so terrible at explaining guys, here is a MUCH better explanation:

Ok, so this bit of HTML is written in a layout template in Pardot, which will generate the contents within the span of "description". That will include the anchor and its text "click here". In the editor, the HTML looks like this:

```
<span class="description">

%%description%%

</span>
```

In the BROWSER it will generate the following:

```
<span class="description">

Not This person?
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_self">Click Here</a >

</span>
```

I would like to edit the "Not this person" and "click here" elements with jQuery! Sorry for not being clear enough earlier!

Comment: What do you mean with "edit" in this context? What exactly do you want to do? Could you provide some code and example output? You can certainly access the any text node in the DOM and modify its value.

Comment: Observe: Yes it is possible. I understand you want to 'edit' the text but we will need more detail. What are you wanting to change it to and when. i.e On click of a button or something happening to trigger the change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### *[demo jsBin](http://jsbin.com/egaken/3/edit)*

```
   var $temp = $('.description').find('a').text('LINK').remove(); // edit, remove and store in a 'variable'
   $('.description').text('I am this person! ').append($temp); // attach
```

Comment: Yesss, thank you, that worked great, and crucially, I understand the code! My jQuery is pretty weak, and I find myself havign to ask for help more times than I am comfortable with. Could you perhaps direct me to a very good video tutorial to help expand my jQuery a little more, Roko? It would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: @WebGuy7767 Hehehehe thanks to you! you made me smile! :) Happy coding and please accept an answer! You have lots of video tuts on youTube! http://blog.themeforest.net/screencasts/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-video-series/ Just do a small Google search.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Since you cannot modify structure, you can use this code to extract `<a>` from `<span>`, update both elements and then merge them:

```
var desc = $(".description");
var a = desc.find("a");
var href = a.attr('href');
var target = a.attr('target');
desc.html("New description text" + '<a href="'+href+'" target="'+target+'">New link label</a>');
```

**Original answer**

You should separate text node "Not This person?" from *a*, perhaps by moving  out of the *span*? Consider this structure:

```
<span id="your_description_id" class="description">
Not This person?
</span>

<a id="your_anchor_id" href="http://www.example.com" target="_self">Click Here</a>
```

And then you can edit those texts with jQuery like that:

```
$("#your_description_id").text("new description");
$("#your_anchor_id").text("new link label");
```

Comment: In case it's of any help, the contents of <span class="description"> </span> are generated dynamically. So there is some mail merge stuff in there... a tag, "%%description%%":

Comment: If anyone is wondering, this is within Landing Page Layout Templates in Pardot: Marketing Automation. I'm not sure if anyone is familiar with the program, but that bit of information may be of some help

Answer (score 0):

If you were able to wrap "Not this person?" in another span then you could use
$('span.description span') and $('span.description a') to find them and edit etc.

```
var englishVersion=$('span.description span').text();
var frenchVersion=somefunction(englishVersion);
$('span.description span').text(frenchversion);
```

etc

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say I want to simply change the text within each HTML element. I need to translate the "Not this person" and "Click Here" to French

Comment: When the page is loaded in the browser, the span is changes to <span id="your_description_id" class="description">
Not This person?
</span>

<a id="your_anchor_id" href="http://www.example.com" target="_self">Click Here</a>